# Facebook API (SDK 3.5) for Android : Both session.isOpened and session.isClosed are false

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

To make things clearer, I'll outline the steps:

- I had previously logged in, so I logout. My logout code (logging out manually through popmenu in android):

> Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
>
> session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

- I close the app, and start it up again. In the first activity, I check if `session==null` and perform the above checks `session.isOpened` and `session.isClosed`. If the session is null or closed, I try to start the `LoginActivity` which fails. The login flow uses this tutorial : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this. Thanks.

Comment: have you set up the UiLifecycleHelper methods correctly?

Comment: Yes, I followed the login tutorial and added the uiHelper methods inside the activity lifecycle methods.